# App crash after click on button (logcat include)

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

So I followed this tutorial [How to receive serial data using android bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450406/how-to-receive-serial-data-using-android-bluetooth)
I did it exactly what is said. But somehow the app crashed after clicking any button there.
My Question are,

1) why would this happen? I mean if the app works well in past ADT why it didn't in recent ADT? what cause of this? cause i found some one also have similar problem from the source of the code http://bellcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/android-and-arduino-bluetooth-communication/

2) how could I fix this? I believe that code already well-structured, initialize the button first then set onclicklistener

3) can somebody tell what it supposed to be mean at this log? I am new in Android Programming
here i include the logcat of report crash,

```
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at com.example.androidarduinopackage.MainActivity.closeBT(MainActivity.java:207)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at com.example.androidarduinopackage.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:90)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
11-13 09:26:44.711 E/AndroidRuntime(14902):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code :

```
package Android.Arduino.Bluetooth;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;  
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
TextView myLabel;
EditText myTextbox;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
OutputStream mmOutputStream;
InputStream mmInputStream;
Thread workerThread;
byte[] readBuffer;
int readBufferPosition;
int counter;
volatile boolean stopWorker;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open);
    Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    Button closeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close);
    myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
    myTextbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);

    //Open Button
    openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try 
            {
                findBT();
                openBT();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    });

    //Send Button
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try 
            {
                sendData();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    });

    //Close button
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try 
            {
                closeBT();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    });
}

void findBT()
{
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
    {
        myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
    }

    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        {
            if(device.getName().equals("MattsBlueTooth")) 
            {
                mmDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
}

void openBT() throws IOException
{
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);        
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

    beginListenForData();

    myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
}

void beginListenForData()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {                
           while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
           {
                try 
                {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();                        
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == delimiter)
                            {
     byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
     System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
     final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
     readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        myLabel.setText(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
           }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
}

void sendData() throws IOException
{
    String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
    msg += "\n";
    mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
    myLabel.setText("Data Sent");
}

void closeBT() throws IOException
{
    stopWorker = true;
    mmOutputStream.close();
    mmInputStream.close();
    mmSocket.close();
    myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
}
}
```

Comment: Please include relevant code. You got the NPE at line 207 which was traced until line 90.

Comment: are you clicking on openButton before clicking on closeButton?

Comment: @Szymon maybe inside method closeBT(), cuz the end of code in line 204. Gil Moshayof no, i check all button and all crash as well

Comment: You can debug as well as count the lines. The code you posted has only 202 lines so maybe it's a different version?

Comment: no I'm pretty sure it's the same code, i use app catlog on android since my USB phone cant detected by my computer. Is that why the line seems difference?

Answer (score 1):

One or more of these of these objects inside closeBT method is null: mOutputStream, mmInputStream, mmSocket.
You should verify that these objects are not null.
If mmSocket is null you should review why this object isn't inicialized. Could be something related to the bluetooth adapter or the code your are using is not compatible with the version of the android.

Comment: how do i do that? since the device and android are not yet paired. can we pass the object to work on null condition? do you have any link that similar with this case?