# Android sample bluetooth code to send a simple string via bluetooth

Tags: android, string, bluetooth, send, sample

I want to send a simple string data such as 'a' from an android device to other one via bluetooth. I looked sample bluetooth code in android sdk but it is so complex for me. I cannot understand how I can send only specific data when I press a button. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You may refer [here] also (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450406/how-to-receive-serial-data-using-android-bluetooth)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
private OutputStream outputStream;
private InputStream inStream;

private void init() throws IOException {
    BluetoothAdapter blueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (blueAdapter != null) {
        if (blueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = blueAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            if(bondedDevices.size() > 0) {
                Object[] devices = (Object []) bondedDevices.toArray();
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) devices[position];
                ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
                BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
                socket.connect();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                inStream = socket.getInputStream();
            }

            Log.e("error", "No appropriate paired devices.");
        } else {
            Log.e("error", "Bluetooth is disabled.");
        }
    }
}

public void write(String s) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
}

public void run() {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytes = 0;
    int b = BUFFER_SIZE;

    while (true) {
        try {
            bytes = inStream.read(buffer, bytes, BUFFER_SIZE - bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your relpy. In addition to this, how can I receive this message from other device?

Comment: @user3374956 in general you need to read data from `InputStream`. How to receive data depends on sender. I've updated code.

Comment: permisssions required are?

Comment: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice[]

Comment: Hi, I have tried exactly the same code, but whenever I send a file (pdf or .doc) to bluetooth printer, it converts it into some hexadecimal code. any suggestion. thanks

Comment: @Shah did U do the bluetooth print ok?

Comment: i get: 
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1 although I am not even calling run()... I am only calling init() and write()

Comment: for people using the above answer may need this link as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3

Comment: device.getUuids() is returning null

Answer (score 6):

I made the following code so that even beginners can understand. Just copy the code and read comments. Note that message to be send is declared as a global variable which you can change just before sending the message. General changes can be done in Handler function.

multiplayerConnect.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class multiplayerConnect extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT=1;
ListView lv_paired_devices;
Set<BluetoothDevice> set_pairedDevices;
ArrayAdapter adapter_paired_devices;
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
public static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
public static final int MESSAGE_READ=0;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE=1;
public static final int CONNECTING=2;
public static final int CONNECTED=3;
public static final int NO_SOCKET_FOUND=4;


String bluetooth_message="00";




@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
Handler mHandler=new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg_type) {
        super.handleMessage(msg_type);

        switch (msg_type.what){
            case MESSAGE_READ:

                byte[] readbuf=(byte[])msg_type.obj;
                String string_recieved=new String(readbuf);

                //do some task based on recieved string

                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:

                if(msg_type.obj!=null){
                    ConnectedThread connectedThread=new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg_type.obj);
                    connectedThread.write(bluetooth_message.getBytes());

                }
                break;

            case CONNECTED:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case CONNECTING:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connecting...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case NO_SOCKET_FOUND:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No socket found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
};



@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.multiplayer_bluetooth);
    initialize_layout();
    initialize_bluetooth();
    start_accepting_connection();
    initialize_clicks();

}

public void start_accepting_connection()
{
    //call this on button click as suited by you

    AcceptThread acceptThread = new AcceptThread();
    acceptThread.start();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"accepting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void initialize_clicks()
{
    lv_paired_devices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Object[] objects = set_pairedDevices.toArray();
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) objects[position];

            ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
            connectThread.start();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"device choosen "+device.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void initialize_layout()
{
    lv_paired_devices = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_paired_devices);
    adapter_paired_devices = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    lv_paired_devices.setAdapter(adapter_paired_devices);
}

public void initialize_bluetooth()
{
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Device doesn't support bluetooth. you can play as Single player",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    //Add these permisions before
//        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
//        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
//        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
//        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    else {
        set_pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (set_pairedDevices.size() > 0) {

            for (BluetoothDevice device : set_pairedDevices) {
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address

                adapter_paired_devices.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }
}


public class AcceptThread extends Thread
{
    private final BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("NAME",MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        serverSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null)
            {
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                mHandler.obtainMessage(CONNECTED).sendToTarget();
            }
        }
    }
}


private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mHandler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING).sendToTarget();

            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
//            bluetooth_message = "Initial message"
//            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE,mmSocket).sendToTarget();
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
}
```

multiplayer_bluetooth.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Challenge player"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_paired_devices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Make sure Device is paired"/>

</LinearLayout>
```