# send/receive data via Bluetooth

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

I'm trying to send/receive a string  from an android device.
I've been googling for the last 3 hours and I can't find anything that just works.
the closest I got was this: [fella](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899475/android-sample-bluetooth-code-to-send-a-simple-string-via-bluetooth)

and I get these errors:

```css
02-19 15:44:17.680    4680-4680/com.example.jelle.bluetoothconnector W/System.err﹕ at com.example.jelle.bluetoothconnector.BluetoothConnection.init(BluetoothConnection.java:38)
02-19 15:44:17.680    4680-4680/com.example.jelle.bluetoothconnector W/System.err﹕ at com.example.jelle.bluetoothconnector.BluetoothConnection.<init>(BluetoothConnection.java:25)
02-19 15:44:17.680    4680-4680/com.example.jelle.bluetoothconnector W/System.err﹕ at com.example.jelle.bluetoothconnector.ConnectorActivity.btnBluetooth_onCLick(ConnectorActivity.java:92)
02-19 15:44:17.680    4680-4680/com.example.jelle.bluetoothconnector W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-19 15:44:17.680    4680-4680/com.example.jelle.bluetoothconnector W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

can anyone help me? I just need some code that can send/receive a string via bluetooth to get me started

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best and most comprehensive example is Android's official bluetooth chat example. You probably do not need to change most of the stuff. See this:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat