# Android paired Bluetooth device not showing app profile

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am not more familiar with **Android Bluetooth functionality**. I have *developed and working code* of connect two Android device via Bluetooth thorough my app. Now the question is that. I have one profile in my app like user profile. Profile has name and picture of user only. Now let's take on example. I have two android device, First device has installed my app with profile name John. and second device has installed my app with profile name Lara. When I connect this two device through my app, If john connect with Lara than I want to show in my application (john's mobile) that John is connected with Lara. It's mean John app show that Lara profile. I have working code, connect two Bluetooth device through coding. But still I can't open paired device app profile name. I am finding the solution for this functionality for last two days, but Still I have not able to show profile in my app. 
I know that this question is not suitable for stack-overflow. but your answer help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your requirement is cool but it's too difficult to achieve .

Comment: thanks, I know that it's difficult. but how can I get this type of functionality ?  Any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899475/android-sample-bluetooth-code-to-send-a-simple-string-via-bluetooth) which will make you send at least one String from a device to the other. What you're looking for is too exhausting for an answer but this is a start. I will not straight up copy the answer I'm linking to because I think you should check it out and up-vote it if it helps you, but I will use some parts of it so you can see if this is what you're looking for.

Basically, you open up a socket between the devices.

```
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
socket.connect();
//Creating objects to hold the output and input from the socket
outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
inStream = socket.getInputStream();
```

You then set up a function to write from one device to the other.

```
public void write(String s) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
}
```

And, to read the string on the other device, you use a byte-buffer and translate it to a String. This is how you get the bytes.

```
bytes = inStream.read(buffer, bytes, BUFFER_SIZE - bytes);
```

Comment: thank you for your cool reply, I am working on same coding structure. If I get success than I will upload my code here. Thanks again.