# Android Bluetooth: Automatically and continuously send the message to a paired android device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have searched a lot for the past weeks but have not found any solution.  I am new to Android, especially Bluetooth programming.  I did read the Bluetooth developer page but it is too complex.

I need to send a String (ex: 40%) continuously from an Android app to another app on a paired Android device without using a button.  It should be automatic.  I need to know how to identify the paired device and send it the send and how to make the paired device receive this string in its app.

Any help please on how to do that please?  I will be very grateful.  Thank you.

Comment: [Android sample bluetooth code to send a simple string via bluetooth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899475/android-sample-bluetooth-code-to-send-a-simple-string-via-bluetooth)

Comment: Also, as far as sending the message continuously without stopping, have you looked at Android services?  [Android service for BLE - how to read and write data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433866/android-service-for-ble-how-to-read-and-write-data)