# Sending a simple string via bluetooth over Android

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

I want to develop an application which sends a simple string, like "Hello World" to a different android device at the click of a Button, via Bluetooth. I looked at Google's BluetoothChat sample but it was too complicated for me to understand. I also looked at a lot of other questions here but couldn't find an answer.

All I found was this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899728/5306756 and it's still not working. The LogCat says "java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice[]".

Could you please provide me with a sample code (or URL containing so) for achieving the same in the simplest way possible?