# Send data from phone to laptop via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, rfcomm

I already successfully paired my Android (6.0.1) phone (Sony Xperia Z3) with my laptop (running Ubuntu 14.04). I can send files back and forth. The Bluetooth connection menu shows that the connection switch switches to ON if files are sent.

I established a persistent connection using:

```
sudo rfcomm connect rfcomm0 [MAC ADDRESS] [CHANNEL]
```

I want to send data from my phone to my laptop via Bluetooth. If I run this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899475/android-sample-bluetooth-code-to-send-a-simple-string-via-bluetooth) the switch goes on as well, but immediately closes the connection down (switch goes back to OFF).

Logcat shows the following warning after calling `init()`:

> W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no
>   BluetoothManagerCallback

and upon calling the `write()` method this exception:

> E/error: error init:java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might
>   closed or timeout, read ret: -1

When connecting using `rfcomm` some channels fail and refuse the connection. My guess is that I am using the wrong channel.

- How can I know which channel to use when calling `rfcomm`?
- How can I specify this channel in my Android app?
- How can I know which UUID to use?
- In the example code the first UUID is used: why?

Comment: Heh...  And all this time I've just been plugging the phone in through the USB.  //No help at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow I could not get it working with the method `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord`.

What I did then was removing:

```
ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
```

and substitute those lines with:

```
int channel = 1; // substitute with channel you are listening on
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",new Class[] { int.class });
BluetoothSocket socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, channel);
```

Then I issued `sudo rfcomm listen rfcomm0` which then shows the channel it is listening on the Linux terminal and I could finally connect!

To answer my own questions:

- **How can I know which channel to use when calling rfcomm?**
  The Linux terminal shows the channel when issuing `sudo rfcomm listen rfcomm0`
- **How can I specify this channel in my Android app?**
  The method I am accessing using reflection has this parameter now (`createRfcommSocket`)
- **How can I know which UUID to use?**
  In this solution none.
- **In the example code the first UUID is used: why?**
  Does not matter for the found solution.