# Fetching vehicle information via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am new to android development. I wanted to know if there is any way to fetch data such as Make, Model etc of a vehicle connected via Bluetooth in Android. As per android documentation the bluetooth device only gives the MAC address and name of the device.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899475/android-sample-bluetooth-code-to-send-a-simple-string-via-bluetooth should help you get started.

Comment: How do you connect to your car? Via MMI or via OBD2? For OBD2 there is a standard, but in most cases you will need a separate Dongle to enable Bluetooth communication. https://www.google.com/search?q=obd2+bluetooth+adapter

Comment: The app will be connected to the car using Bluetooth Headset profile which is available for most of the cars. MMI I believe is Bluetooth's profile for Audi models. We would not be connecting through OBD as of now. Wanted to know if the bluetooth headset profile of the car gives information about make and model of the car.