# Make a Bluetooth Auto Send Chat

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to send an auto message from bluetooth, example-:When the user clicks the button send message-"click".As far as I have noticed the message is sent in bytes and I cannot alter it.

Comment: don't you find in google...

Comment: Don't I get what in google?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899475/android-sample-bluetooth-code-to-send-a-simple-string-via-bluetooth  -check this link

Comment: looks good,I will get back as soon as it works for me

Comment: kudos,Worked,thanks a ton