# How to broadcast a message via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-broadcast, broadcasting

Is that possible to broadcast a message ( not a audio stream, just a simple text message ) via bluetooth ? And if it is possible how can I do it ?

Comment: why ask question which has 1000+ answers and tutorials on google

Comment: Can you kindly give me a link, please ? I have already searched and did not find anything.

Comment: Took me 1sec. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899475/android-sample-bluetooth-code-to-send-a-simple-string-via-bluetooth

Comment: You see I want to broadcast data, not to send it to a certain one.

Comment: What you mean by broadcast?

Comment: I am broadcasting "Hello" from device A and other devices without connecting to A getting that message. How I know all BLE ( like rangefinder, termometer, ... ) works in that way. I mean you can read the data without connecting to BLE.

Comment: Ok. Now I get it. It's called proximity marketing. You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_marketing) and [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-advertise-android-as-a-bluetooth-le-peripheral--cms-25426)

Comment: Thank you, will look it now

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I want :)