# How to receive serial data from arduino using bluetooth?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

I am new to Arduino I got 0 knowledge in it and also this is my first time coding with bluetooth, so I wanted to ask how can I actually receive serial data from arduino for example and change the textview in my android:

[image: this]

I want to get this value from arduino and change the textview in my android. So it will be something like `if (xxx == "11"){ textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);}` but I don't know how to write/how to get the arduino value and declare in android.

Comment: Check this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599490/how-to-simply-pass-a-string-from-android-studio-kotlin-to-arduino-serial-bluet/54950438#54950438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a HC-05 bluetooth module for example, and the use of the Serial library.
Try to define a new serial port and then send your data by it.
Arduino code :

```
SoftwareSerial btSerial (12, 13); //TX sur 12 et RX sur 13
btSerial.begin(9600);
btSerial.println("Link Started !");
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for the arduino code I used, wait a sec'.

Comment: I did put a link in my first comment under your question, it is written in kotlin and has everything you need.