# send and receive data via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

you can say that i'm new in android development, i need some help to synchronize some data in two devices with my application, i have done all necessary things like searching for available devices and pairing and unpairing ... all what i need now is how to make a connection between the two devices and send and receive data, to explain more, i need to select a device from my listview and connect with it, after that lets say that i have a text field and a textview and a button, when i click on the button i need to send the text in the textfield of the first device to the textview of other device and vise-versa.
here is all my code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private Button onBtn;
    private Button offBtn;
    private Button listBtn;
    private Button findBtn;
    private TextView text;
    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
    private ListView myListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> BTArrayAdapter;
    private String tag = "debugging";
    protected static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
            .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
    protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.i(tag, "in handler");
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
            case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                // DO something
                ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(
                        (BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECT", 0).show();
                String s = "successfully connected";
                connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
                Log.i(tag, "connected");
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String string = new String(readBuf);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, 0).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // take an instance of BluetoothAdapter - Bluetooth radio
        myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (myBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            onBtn.setEnabled(false);
            offBtn.setEnabled(false);
            listBtn.setEnabled(false);
            findBtn.setEnabled(false);
            text.setText("Status: not supported");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Your device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            BTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            myListView.setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            onBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.turnOn);
            onBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    on(v);
                }
            });

            offBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.turnOff);
            offBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    off(v);
                }
            });

            listBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paired);
            listBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    list(v);
                }
            });

            findBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
            findBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    find(v);
                }
            });

            // create the arrayAdapter that contains the BTDevices, and set it
            // to the ListView

            myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                        myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    }

                    BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(position);
                    if (pairedDevices.contains(selectedDevice)) {

                        if (unpairDevice(selectedDevice))
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Device unpaired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Problem while unpairing device",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        if (pairDevice(selectedDevice)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Device paired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(
                                    selectedDevice);
                            connect.start();
                        } else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Problem while pairing device",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            });

        }
    }

    // For Pairing
    private boolean pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Log.d("pairDevice()", "Start Pairing...");
            Method m = device.getClass()
                    .getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
            m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // For UnPairing
    private boolean unpairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Log.d("unpairDevice()", "Start Un-Pairing...");
            Method m = device.getClass()
                    .getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
            m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void on(View view) {
        if (!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent turnOnIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOnIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth turned on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is already on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                text.setText("Status: Enabled");
            } else {
                text.setText("Status: Disabled");
            }
        }
    }

    public void list(View view) {
        BTArrayAdapter.clear();
        // get paired devices
        // pairedDevices.clear();
        pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // put it's one to the adapter
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
            BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Show Paired Devices",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the
                // arrayAdapter
                devices.add(device);
                BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"
                        + device.getAddress());
                BTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    public void find(View view) {
        if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            // the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovery cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovering new devices",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BTArrayAdapter.clear();
            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        }
    }

    public void off(View view) {
        myBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        text.setText("Status: Disconnected");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            Log.i(tag, "construct");
            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server
                // code
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(tag, "get socket failed");

            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.i(tag, "connect - run");
            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.i(tag, "connect - succeeded");
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                Log.i(tag, "connect failed");
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                }
                return;
            }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)

            mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
        }

        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer; // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    buffer = new byte[1024];
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: post edited, i'm looking for what should i add to send and reseive data

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899475/android-sample-bluetooth-code-to-send-a-simple-string-via-bluetooth#autocomment84444121) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450406/how-to-receive-serial-data-using-android-bluetooth) Hope it helps!