# TextView won't update within handler

Tags: android, bluetooth, textview

I've tried to make an app that receives a String through Buetooth from Arduino.

Its format is `"#100.23+123.12+90.45+101.20~`, `+` is a separator between four double number, starts with # and ends with ~.

I've followed the tutorial [here](https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/android-sendreceive-data-with-arduino-using-bluetooth-part-2/). Everything seems ok but mostly the four `Textview`s won't update with values as I have assigned for them.

This is the code that updates the `Textview`, it relies on the `onCreate()` function.

Sometimes it does update (rarely), and most the time it just doesn't change.
Please help me with this, I have a little knowledge about android. Thanks

```
    sensorView0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView0);
    sensorView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView1);
    sensorView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView2);
    sensorView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView3);
    //sensorView0.setText("Temp111111");
    bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == handlerState) {                                     //if message is what we want
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                                                // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
                recDataString.append(readMessage);                                      //keep appending to string until ~

                int startOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("#");
                int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~",startOfLineIndex);                    // determine the end-of-line
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // make sure there data before ~
                    String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(startOfLineIndex, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string

                    if (dataInPrint.charAt(0) == '#')                             //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                    {
                        int startPos =1;
                        int endPos = dataInPrint.indexOf("+");
                        String sensor0 = dataInPrint.substring(startPos, endPos);             //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
                        startPos =endPos +1;
                        endPos = dataInPrint.indexOf("+",endPos+1);
                        String sensor1 = dataInPrint.substring(startPos, endPos);            //same again...
                        startPos =endPos +1;
                        endPos = dataInPrint.indexOf("+",endPos+1);
                        String sensor2 = dataInPrint.substring(startPos, endPos);
                        startPos =endPos +1;
                        endPos = dataInPrint.indexOf("+",endPos+1);
                        String sensor3 = dataInPrint.substring(startPos, endPos);

                        sensorView0.setText(" Heart Rate = " + sensor0 + "bpm");    //update the textviews with sensor values
                        sensorView1.setText(" Blood = " + sensor1 + "V");
                        sensorView2.setText(" Sensor 2 Voltage = " + sensor2 + "V");
                        sensorView3.setText(" Sensor 3 Voltage = " + sensor3 + "V");

                    }
                    recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    //clear all string data

                    dataInPrint = " ";
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please format your post properly with proper punctuation and indention. Your post burns my eyes when I try to read it. May I suggest using Grammarly if you're not a native English speaker?

Comment: In my opinion, your code would be cleaner if you performed a `split` on your "dataInPrint" string.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450406/how-to-receive-serial-data-using-android-bluetooth)  really help me out with my problem.